# Segue from a SubView (tableview) to a ModalView (storyboard)

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4, storyboard, xcode4.3

I have a RootView called ExploreViewController

Here I load a subView with: `[self.view addSubview:self.wallPostsTableViewController.view];`

This working fine, but now I want to hit a cell and open the Detail info of that sell, normally I use prepareToSegue and preformSegue in didSelectRowAtIndexPath...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// call super because we're a custom subclass.
[super tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ExploreModalSegue" sender:self];
```

}

and

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender { 
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ExploreModalSegue"]) {
    MuseumViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
    NSInteger row = [[self tableView].indexPathForSelectedRow row];
    detailViewController.detailItems = [self.objects objectAtIndex:row];  
}
```

}

and that gives an error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver () has no segue with identifier 'ExploreModalSegue''

I need something to call the detailViewController with the right information of that cell and I want to use StoryBoard for that detailViewController?

Comment: a little confused about what you're asking...did you create the segue in storyboards and specify the identifier as 'ExploreModalSegue' yet?

Comment: Yes I did that. But the I did from the rootview to the ExploreView, because the rootview not have a tableview prototype cell but is done with code (subview) can I do a segue to the detail view or can I use my storyboard (detail)view at all with code?

Comment: why is your subview a tableviewcontroller and not a tableview object? Adding a tableviewcontroller on top of another viewcontroller is bound to give you problems.

Comment: I wanted to use that because I'm using a subclass of UITableView and CustomCells, also using the Parse.com SDK for backend, I'm not so senior to change that and start building from scratch, thats why I love StoryBoard and Prototype Cells